# Alt-Az or Polar?

Tags: telescope

I have a Meade wedge that I am to install on one of their LX200 telescopes. Will I be able to align in alt-az afterwards? Is polar easier or harder to make an alignment? Any other tips welcome. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean will you be able to align in alt-az with the wedge installed? If so, probably not.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I installed the wedge this evening.. Polar it is then!

Comment: I'd not really familiar with meade hand set computers but I imagine they have an alignment helper routine built in you can use in either mode. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, they do have a polar setup. Their manual though, is very hard to read. I have to read things over and over, and then translate bits and pieces to items on hand. I suspect that, as they've changed models, they haven't updated their documentation. Thank you for the response..

Comment: Are you going with the wedge to start getting into astrophotography? The folks at r/astrophotography on reddit would be able to give you some help with any problems.

Comment: Brilliant. That's just what I could use.and yep, I want to start getting some planetary images..

Comment: It would be nice if we can get this fleshed out as an actual 'answer' below. Thanks. (cc @asawyer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the wedge in place, you will only do polar alignments.  If you want to go back to az/el, you must remove the wedge.

For me polar alignments are much faster and easier than az/el alignments.
For polar:

1. level the mount
2. Set your latitude on the wedge
3. Let the auto alignment point the scope at dec 90 and manually spin the mount until you align on Polaris.  You use the manual controls on the wedge for this, not the hand controller.
4. Do a one star alignment on an overhead star.  I always use Vega in the summertime.  You use the hand controller for this.

If you haven't moved the mount since last time (or if it is permanently mounted) all you have to do is power up and do a one star alignment.  Easy!

Comment: Thanks John. Your answer is a keeper.. I'll print it and use it asap..

Comment: The MAPUG user group is a great resource for LX200 info.  Their checklists are very handy and work much better than the info in the Meade manuals. http://thadlabs.com/MAPUG/AstroDesigns/MAPUG/ArhvList.htm